# Matching groups of entries (rows) throughout data set

Tags: excel, excel-2007, concatenation

I am working with a large data set containing information about certain items

The items are structured so that they all have seven main sections. Within each main section their is a variable number of parts, that the items are made of.
The items uses only one part from each main section. So all items consists of seven (identical) main sections and seven parts.

I am looking to group items togheter which are precisely identical. I mean the items that uses the same part in all the main sections.

Is there an Excel/math wizard out there who can help me out with this? 
I have all the data, but I can't make Excel do this task for me..

Comment: You don't provide much to work with. A data sample might help, and a mocked up sample of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data structure (which is not quite clear), you could use a helper column where you concatenate the contents of all seven main sections. Then use this helper column to sort and group the data. For example, if the main sections are in columns A to G, use a formula like this in column H:

```
=A2&"_"&B2&"_"&C2&"_"&D2&"_"&E2&"_"&F2&"_"&G2
```

Now sort the data by column H and all identical items will be placed together.